# gitolite admin DENIED by fallthru

Tags: mac, gitolite

I have an issue with SSH keys and gitolite on my macbook.

Gitolite is running on my debian server: `gitolite3 3.6.4-1 (Debian) on git 2.7.4`

gitolite-admin/keydir i have the keys bob.pub and admin.pub
They are different keys.

my conf file is basically:

```
# this repo
repo gitolite-admin
    RW+     =   admin

repo myrepo
    RW+     =   bob
```

My ~/.ssh/config file is simply this to specify we use a different port:

```
Host gitserver
    IdentityFile ~/keys/bob
    Port 2222
```

I am testing with the command:

```
git clone git@gitserver:myrepo.git
```

These are the logs under /home/git/.gitolite/logs/

When ssh from my linux system, it works fine.

```
2016-10-14.15:54:53 11635   ssh ARGV=bob    SOC=git-upload-pack 'myrepo'    FROM=192....
2016-10-14.15:54:53 11635   pre_git myrepo  bob R   any refs/.*
2016-10-14.15:54:53 11635       system,git,shell,-c,git-upload-pack '/home/git//repositories/myrepo.git'
2016-10-14.15:54:53 11635   END
```

However, when I do the same thing with the SAME key on my macbook air, it seems that

```
2016-10-14.15:56:07 11652   ssh ARGV=admin  SOC=git-upload-pack 'myrepo'    FROM=192.168.0.105
2016-10-14.15:56:07 11652   die R any myrepo admin DENIED by fallthru<<newline>>(or you mis-spelled the reponame)
```

What I think is happening:

1. the underlying ssh connection is using the correct user (git) and key (bob) to get onto the server. It is done using /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys (generated by gitolite) I can actually see in this file the `command="/usr/share/gitolite3/gitolite-shell bob"` showing that the command argument matching the key is correct.
2. However after ssh connection, for some reason the command is changed to have the argument admin INSTEAD of bob!.

Again. 
It does not happen on my linux machine. 
This only happens on my macbook.

What DOES work from the mac is that i can clone testing or gitolite-admin. 
Even with the bob key, when it really should be the admin key!
I think that this might actually be a security hole in gitolight!

I am running. 3.6.4 and there is nothing in the release notes of 3.6.5 or 3.6.6 to indicate a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else coming here with a similar problem, there is a reply by gitolite author on the mailing list: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gitolite/VRLAQaN2QoE/7EWN1I82BQAJ

> I suggest you add the word "IdentitiesOnly" to your ~/.ssh/config and try again.  Kill ssh-agent, keychain, or any of those kinds of beasts also and restart them, adding only the "bob" key.
>
> For good measure, move the admin private key out of the box completely.

Comment: It seems you are right "IdentitiesOnly yes" is the full line to be added to the file. 
Its a strange thing that ssh tries other keys than what is listed as a default behaviour. In this case gitolite-admin is doing the right thing and ssh configuration behaviour itself is "odd".